# sails blueprints query in url not working

Tags: search, sails.js

I have various GET http calls to my api with the following format:

`/api/posts?userId=3`

However, it is not filtering posts by its `userId` column, and just returns all posts, regardless of the posts' userId.

This syntax has worked in past projects I've had also, and is documented [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where). (The example they give is `GET /purchase?amount=99.99`).

Questions I've seen do not address the query language via defaults routes in this way, so I'm having trouble finding help. Any guesses on what could be going wrong?

UPDATE:

**What does work as expected**

- `req.query` is getting set and read by policies (eg, `?userId=3` is found by `req.param("userId")`)
- `/api/posts?userId=3&populate=userId` populates the `userId` field, (but still returns all posts for all users)
- filtering by primary key (eg `?id=5`) filters and returns only one record as expected
- When working in the api, or in sails console, (eg `Posts.find({userId: 3})`) works

**What does not work as expected**

- filtering by foreign keys (eg `?userId=6`)
- filtering by non-foreign keys (eg `?name=test`)
- filtering using `where` (eg `&where={"userId":1}`)

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas... do you have a PostsController? Is your blueprint rest option turned on? I assume `userId` connects to a `User` model... does the filtering work if you try to filter on a non-linked field?

Comment: @arbuthnott I do have a PostsController, and blueprint rest is set to `true`. And yes, userId attribute in the model is `userId: {model: 'users', required: true}`. But that shouldn't matter, since each record has a userId column  and so I believe the query should work either way (?). 

Re: the unlinked field, `/api/posts?userId=3&asdf=3` likewise returns all posts, if that answers your question

Comment: I don't have a `find` controller action defined in the controller though, it just uses the waterline defaults

Comment: I asked about a non-linked field because under the hood, I know that Waterline may name a linked field something unexpected (like `_post_user` etc), and maybe this is a source of error when using the blueprint api. I would want to know if something like `/api/posts?title=sometitle` filters properly. If it does, I might start diving into Waterline and the raw db to see what my userId field really looks like at the db level, and see if there's a disconnect in the naming of linked fields.

Comment: @arbuthnott mmm, good thought. Yeah, other queries (that are non foreign-keys) are also not filtering results. But populating using the query (eg `?populate=userId` does work, for what it's worth.

Comment: CORRECTION: filtering by primary key (eg,`?id=5`) is working...but yeah, nothing else

Comment: Can be dumb, but are you doing a parseInt to that id?

Comment: @paulogdm I'm not, but I tried doing that in a policy and setting req.query.userId to that parsed value just in case it might make a difference, and it didn't. But yeah, I wouldn't think that would change anything either way (?). Honestly though, any ideas no matter how farfetched are welcome at this point; I'm at a complete loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was adding a "where" clause to every query in a policy (eg, `"where: {"status": "active"}}`). Having a "where" in the query string automatically [overrides the other params](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/parse-blueprint-options.js#L127), and so nothing else was getting seen. (To be precise, if you have a where clause, other criteria never get seen)

For some reason, the "where" was also not working to set the search criteria for sails 0.12.13, so I ended up hacking the `parseCriteria` function [actionUtils](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil.js#L207) in sails and using the one they have for v.1 and that worked for me.

Hope that helps anyone in the future